Как вызвать функцию внутри windows процесса?
Изучаю питон, пытаюсь в игре вызвать функцию send(), которая будет отправлять пакет по сокету.
SendFuncType = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(
    ctypes.c_int,
    wintypes.HANDLE,  
    ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ubyte), 
    ctypes.c_int,  
    ctypes.c_int 
)

def main(socket_handle = 0x0B40):
    process_name = "game.exe"
    offset = 0x63BB19  # Офсет для функции send

    hModule = get_module_handle(process_name)
    send_addr = hModule + offset

    send_fn = SendFuncType(send_addr)
    data = (ctypes.c_ubyte * 15)(0x22, 0x0D, 0x0C, 0x29, 0x00, 0x2B, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xA0, 0x30, 0x08, 0x00)
    send_fn(socket_handle, data, len(data), 0)

Но я столкнулся с тем, что у меня нет доступа к этой функции:
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000F90000

Насколько я понял, мне нужно создавать в процессе отдельный поток с помощью CreateRemoteThread, но я абсолютно не понимаю, как вызвать эту функцию внутри потока. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Скорее у вас нет доступа к памяти другого процесса. Винда защищает процессы, чтобы в них посторонние не шарились.

@CrazyElf так я и пишу о том, что мне нужно создавать отдельный опток внутри процесса который будет вызывать эту функцию, именно так в моем случае можно избавиться от ошибки доступа. Я пытаюсь понять как это правильно сделать.

@insolor с помощью CreateRemoteTread у меня получается инжектить код и вызвать функцию, во всяком случае при запуске скрипта x32dbg мне отдает лог о том, что в игре был создан новый поток который обращается к функции send. Возможно я неправильно передаю аргументы.

А, увидел в доках, можно по адресу создавать, как вы делаете https://i.sstatic.net/fzpsOby6.png. Тут может быть несоответствие соглашений вызова - как вариант попробуйте CFUNCTYPE вместо WINFUNCTYPE (хотя если нет переменного количества аргументов, то вряд ли этот вариант будет использоваться).
